# Which method of dealing with transaction deadlocks is preferable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, database-administration

So I'm a financial analyst that uses SQL a lot (only for reading, never to write to the DB), and only recently have I started paying attention to the issue of deadlocks.  I never knew that running SQL reports off a live production database is bad practice, until recently that is.  From  my research, it appears running your reporting off a data warehouse is ideal, and I'll suggest our company look into it.  For the time being, I really need to resolve the deadlock issue we get about once or twice a week, which causes major issues for our ERP users in the office, and employees logging in their time in the manufacturing floor.

I run a ton of reports in MS Query inside of Excel, and I've noticed that 99% of the time there's an issue, killing all the Microsoft Office processes in Activity monitor clears up the issue.  Here's a screenshot of what that looks like:

[image]

I've no idea how to properly read this stuff, but I presume in the example above, it's the process with the LCK_M_S wait type that has caused a deadlock.  Also, I was just reading a comment from an Excel developer that states:

> Excel (and other single user environment tools) have no real good way of defining the boundaries of a transaction. In many cases an exclusive lock is maintained from first opening of the table throughout the whole lifetime of that session i.e. until Excel is closed

This seems pretty bad, because it would mean that if I don't kill the Microsoft Office processes manually, the only other way to resolve the deadlock would be for everyone in the company to close every Excel file that has queries in it, which is obviously not an ideal solution.  I also have a lot of queries in Power BI files, which shows up as "Mashup Engine" in activity monitor, and I've never seen any issues with this, and I have no idea why.  I'd imagine the deadlock potential is still there

Anyway, hope that's enough background so that potential solutions aside from a data warehouse can be recommended.  Here's a few proposed solutions I've seen proposed based on my research:

**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED**

I see that the main issue with this is dirty reads and other similar issues that may lead to inaccurate data being returned.  The thing is, we're a fairly small company, it's not like we have countless transactions being processed by our ERP every minute like a large corporation.  I've tried running some of my code with this statement and so far, most of the queries I've run are identical to the ones without that statement.  I think this seems like a good solution, but perhaps there is something I'm missing.

**SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW**

So this apparently doesn't prevent deadlocks, but at least allows you to choose the deadlock victim.  When one of my Excel queries deadlocks with, let's say someone creating a purchase order in our ERP system, I assume that whenever the ERP transaction is chosen as the deadlock victim, that's when parts of our ERP start freezing up.  If I set every Excel query to a low deadlock priority so that it's always chosen as the deadlock victim, would that be a good solution to ensure our ERP never freezes up because of a deadlock caused by an Excel query?  This method would guarantee accurate data, but since deadlocks will still occur, not sure it's ideal.

**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT and SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON**

Honestly, these two are still pretty confusing as hell to me but thought they were worth mentioning in case anyone thinks they're the best solution for my case

Lastly, I'll include a sample query that I know for a fact clashes frequently with our Purchasing department in case it helps.  This report is used by our Supply Chain Manager and is often in his desktop via Excel with a refresh rate of 120 minutes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pr.PONum,
    CASE
        WHEN pr.JobNo LIKE '%E%' THEN SUBSTRING(pr.JobNo, 1, CHARINDEX('E', pr.JobNo)-1) 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(pr.JobNo, 1, CHARINDEX('-', pr.JobNo)-1)
        END AS [Order #],
    pd.Status, 
    p.VendCode,
    pr.PartNo, 
    CAST(pd.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc], 
    pd.QtyOrd, 
    pd.QtyRec, 
    pd.QtyCancel, 
    pd.QtyReject,
    CAST(p.DateEnt AS DATETIME) AS [DateEntered],
    CAST(p.DateReq AS DATETIME) AS [Original Due Date],
    CAST(pd.DueDate AS DATETIME) AS [DueDate],
    CAST(pd.DateFinished AS DATETIME) AS [DateFinished]
FROM POReleases pr
    JOIN PODet pd ON pr.PONum = pd.PONum AND pr.PartNo = pd.PartNo
    JOIN PO p ON pr.PONum = p.PONum AND CAST(p.DateEnt AS DATETIME) >= '20190101'
WHERE (pd.JobNo LIKE '%-%'
    OR pd.JobNo = '<Multiple>')
    AND pr.JobNo NOT LIKE '%Stock%'
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1 DESC
```

Comment: Read uncommitted is absolutely NOT the solution you want to use. It does some really fun things like randomly (and not repeatable) return missing and/or duplicate rows. For a financial application is absolutely unacceptable. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere Keep in mind that there are lots of implicit transactions that can and do happen in sql server on a regular basis.

Comment: Do you actually mean deadlock? Or is this just regular locking? If its just preventing other activity then its probably just regular locking - deadlock are usually discovered quite quickly.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I don't believe it's regular locking, because it only happens once or twice a week or there may be weeks where it doesn't happen at all.  When it happens, activity in certain ERP modules can be locked out for hours, I don't think regular locking would cause that.  We have roughly the same amount of SQL reports running every week, if regular locking was an issue, we would have the issue pretty much every day, no?

Comment: @user1452574 not at all. A deadlock can never complete, and is detected as such and then killed off by SQL Server - usually fairly quickly. So unless you have a specific notification that a deadlock occurred (you can query the database to find out), its probably just locking, one process holding a lock for a very long time and preventing any other process from accessing that resource. Handling long locks vs deadlocks are quite different things, so I would suggest making your question accurate.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks Dale, it seems you may be correct.  I went ahead and turned on trace flag 1222 to capture future deadlocks.  Next time we have an issue, if no deadlock gets logged, then I'll know that's not the problem.  At that point, I suppose the problem would be blocking, caused by a process that is holding on to a lock for too long,causing other processes that need that table to wait, correct?  I need to do some research on that and potential solutions.  Thanks again

Comment: That would be my guess. A terrible, but practical, solution might be to use the hint `with (nolock)` on your queries from Excel. You run the risk of potentially having slightly incorrect data, but it won't lock the rest of the queries.

Comment: @DaleBurrell It is my understanding that with (nolock) only prevents deadlocks, but wouldn't locking still occur?  Also, with (nolock) is the same as set isolation read uncommitted right?  Only difference being that one is for the whole script and the other is set per table?  Here's a video I watched recently regarding with (nolock) still taking out locks that can cause blocking:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G1sgS4fFoQ&t=145s Let me know your thoughts

Comment: `nolock` does as it says, it means no locks are taken on the table specified, for the query in question. It prevents that table from being involved in **any** locking issue (certainly not just deadlocks). I think you are correct when you say its pretty much the same as isolation read uncommitted https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/